# Optimal schema to store ordered list of different objects types in postgres (or recommend another DB solution)?

Tags: database, postgresql, firebase, schema, publish-subscribe

relatively new to system design so looking for some advice on a project.In summary, I want to create a view of data which is comprised of an ordered list of different object types.

In this example I am building an `activity` page that multiple users will be sharing and adding/removing/etc. different activities (new activity pages can be created too). Each type of activity is rigid in its data model so I would like to keep them in their own tables i.e. a table for `restaurants`, a separate table for `dance_venues`, a separate table for `hikes`. However a user can add any of these activity types to the shared activity page.

For example I login to view activity page 1 and I see a page like

**Activity Page 1**

1. 9am - Starbucks

- location
- open hours

2. Park Hike

- length
- difficulty

3. Outback steakhouse

- location
- open hours

4. Karaoke

- hours
- cost
- 21+

The list of activities could theoretically be represented by a linked list where each node is its own type but I am unsure of how to optimal store this in postgres.

Any and all advice is appreciated!

Some possible solutions I am considering.

1. Have an `activity` table that has a column for every possible foreign key type (or every possible type of activity) where in practice only one column would over be filled which is the one I would use to query for the activity itself.

| activity_page | restaurant_key | dance_venues_key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| activity page1 | rest key |  |
| activity page1 |  | dance key |
| activity page2 |  | dance key |

This is not ideal as I have no idea how many activity types there will be (and new ones will always be added) and I have to do some ugly query manipulation to only get one activity back per activity_page row

2. Denormalize and store the entire activity page as JSONB col. This has the obvious trade off that I am losing a single source of truth for these activity types and it will be basically impossible to manage the activity JSONB column with 100% fidelity but it is cleaner in a sense and helps in the cases of users trying to change the order of different activities on an activity page at the same time (and does not require additional queries to fetch the related objects). If I am doing this I might as well use a no-sql solution (see below). I am also unclear on the size limitation of JSONB

2.5 Denormalize and store the activity page JSON data in no-sql document solution like firebase/firestore where activates are read/copied from the postgres tables and added to the activity page documents in firestore. However I don't have much experience in pub/sub or subscribing to updates to the firestore documents if someone could comment on how easy or hard it is to have multiple users making changes to the same document.

3. Somehow store the type of foreign key that is at each node in the list. I have tried researching if this is possible in Postgres but have not found anything that promising. Something like

| activity_page | foreign_key | foreign_table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| activity page1 | key | table |
| activity page1 | key | table |
| activity page2 | key | table |

This seems the cleanest if it's possible but I am not sure how to accomplish it.

Other notes:

1. I am using a graphql yoga server side
2. I don't expect each activity page's list to exceed 100 activities

Comment: I think I might go with approach 3 and build the foreign table reference into the query client side

Comment: not ideal since the DB column is just a plain `Int` type and I will have to first fetch the activity rows then build the activity query itself but I think it will work